# Spring data elastic search with sort not working

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using elastic search db and spring data.
Following is my document in which I am searching and that search result should return **sorted** and **pageable** list.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = { "id" })
@Document(indexName = "job", type = "job")
public class JobDocument implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, store = true)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, store = true)
    private String desc;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, store = true)
    private LocalDateTime dateTime; // java.Time
}
```

I am searching text in `desc` field and want to sort it by `dateTime` field. My search service does following,

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + desc + "*").lenient(true).field("desc"));
NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
searchQuery.withPageable(pageable);
searchQuery.withSort(SortBuilders.fieldSort("dateTime")
.order(SortOrder.DESC))
searchQuery.withQuery(queryBuilder);
Page<JobDocument> jobs = jobRepo.search(searchQuery.build());
```

Following is my repo,

```
public interface JobDAO extends ElasticsearchRepository<JobDocument, String>
{}
```

Search and pageable is working but Sorting is not working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: why are you sorting an analyzed field ?

Comment: Thats typo. I have edited question.

Comment: @PrashantShilimkar have you find a solution? I'm having the same issue

Comment: No. not yet. looks like no one knows it :D

Answer (score 1):

Their is a sort option available in pageable object.Instead of using the sort and pagination separately, you can add them into a single object PageRequest.

```
BoolQueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery();
queryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery("*" + desc + "*").lenient(true).field("desc"));
NativeSearchQueryBuilder searchQuery = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder();
searchQuery.withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10, Sort.Direction.DESC, "dateTime"));
searchQuery.withQuery(queryBuilder);
```